# how to use "mysqld -O thread_stack=#"

Tags: mysql, java

I keep getting this error whether I run my query from the terminal or from within `Java`.

Anyone has some instructions on how to resolve this?

> Thread stack overrun:  5768 bytes used of a 131072 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.
>       Use 'mysqld -O thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack.

Comment: Please don't cross post your questions to multiple stackexchange sites. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15123/how-to-use-mysqld-o-thread-stack

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to your my.cnf if it doesn't exist or replace the 128K setting if it does. Also you'll need to restart Mysql for it to take effect since the setting is not [dynamic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_thread_stack).

```
thread_stack = 192K
```

This is usually the default on most modern Linux distros

Comment: That didn't work. I am using XAMPP so I click stop on the icon then start. My computer is mac osx lion